# How to use SwiftUI Color in UIKit View

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui

I am using the [iOS Charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) wrapped in UIViewRepresentable to use a line chart within a SwiftUI project. I need to set some colors on the chart in UIColor that match the system colors that I have used in the rest of the SwiftUI project. I assumed that UIColor.red, for example, would be the same as Color.red in swiftUI, however this is not the case with any of the default system colors. They all are slightly different than each other. How can I bridge these two views and use the SwiftUI colors I have used in the wrapped UIView?

I've seen that there is a way to initialize a SwiftUI Color from a UIColor using

```
Color(UIColor.red)
```

but have found no equivalent to go the other way. Here's a example of the differences in the colors.

UIColor
[image]

Color
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the new UIColor.systemRed?  Given this is the new dark mode-aware red in UIKit, I wonder if itis  the same as SwiftUI's .red?

Comment: @flanker Yep that was the problem. Thanks!! Guess I need to use the correct versions of UIColor to match the dark mode-aware swiftUI colors!

Comment: hey, I'm trying to use Charts library in my swiftui project! I wanna make exactly what you've made in the pictures. do you mind to give a little help?

Comment: There is a bar chart library, you can check it out as well https://github.com/dawigr/BarChart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With support for dark mode in iOS 13, the UIColors have been updated: `.red` has been replaced by `.systemRed` which has slightly different tones of red to allow it to support light and dark modes.  This will be equivalent to SwiftUI's `.red`.